# jQuery DataTables plugin -- adding a custom option select filter

Tags: jquery, plugins, filter, datatables

Anyone know how to add a custom option select filter to a jQuery DataTable?

Basically, like this [example page](http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) but instead of having min/max text fields... change them to select options.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easier than I thought it would be:

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Initialise datatables */
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    /* Add event listener to the dropdown input */
    $('select#engines').change( function() { oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val() ); } );
} );
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="engines">
    <option value="">- Select -</option>
    <option value="1.8">1.8</option>
    <option value="1.9">1.9</option>
</select>
```

Comment: says TypeError: oTable.fnFilter is not a function@Jeffrey

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a regular expression that will do it.  Making a minimum or maximium is fairly easy.  Trying to do both at the same time gets tricky.  Here is one that will return all numbers 13+:

```
oTable.fnFilter("([1-9][3-9]|[2-9][0-9]|[0-9]{3,})", 1, true);
```

This says: 13-99 (excluding 20, 21, 22, 31, 32, etc)
           20-99
           100+