# Ajax datatable scrolling for large dataset

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, datatables

I have a very large dataset (a few million rows) that I would like to have be scrollable on an HTML page.  I have been using jQuery DataTable Scroller with some success, but I am having some trouble with updating the result with new data (for example, after adding a filter, which I am doing external to DataTable).  I am curious what other tools folks are using for such a problem.

To clarify, I cannot load the entire dataset at once.  With scroller, I have a setup like this:

```
var oTable = $('#main_table').dataTable({
"bProcessing":true,
"bServerSide":true,
"bDeferRender":true,
"sScrollX":"100%",
"sScrollY":"500px",
"sAjaxSource":"/list/b",
"oScroller": {
"trace":true},
"fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
  aoData.push( {"name": "search", "value": $('#fSearch').val() } );
},
"sDom": '<"clear">rtiS'
} );
```

Comment: are you reloading all of the data or just appending/removing rows when you update?

Comment: I'm never reloading (or even loading) all the data.  To answer your question, though, the underlying data are read-only.  Only the query (which limits the result set) changes.  Functionally, this equates to needing to "refresh" the table data including row counts, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879540/jquery-datatables-plugin-adding-a-custom-option-select-filter